# Spinner for each Angular Material component

Tags: angular, angular-material, primeng

Angular PrimeNG table has [loading] property for showing spinner while data is being loaded. I need to implement that property for material's components, not for tables only but other components too, for example input forms. I am new to Angular. Just would like to know how to create a spinner for a specific div, not for the entire page.

Comment: why not to create custom loader for such cases?

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: @Aspram refer to my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used ngx-loading package. It has the needed functionality.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-loading

Answer (score 1):

create custom loader with class and html you can hide other element till this data not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Better in such scenarios is create one separate shared component say `LoaderComponent` and Placed somewhere in the root level say app.component.html.

and whenever needed you can show/hide that loader component globally via shared service.

PS: As a shared component is always better to create a module for that component so that you can even use this among several lazy loaded modules as well.